# InputStream value is -1 when moving from background to foreground in ios

Tags: ios, sockets, inputstream

Created App based on socket communication. When the app is in the foreground it is working fine. When power off and unlock the screen `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` is getting called which reads the data.

```
unsigned char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

NSInteger bytesRead = [inputStream read: buf maxLength: BUFFER_SIZE];
```

bytesRead has value as -1. It crashes the application.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: -1 indicates that the stream has closed (which you would expect since your app went into the background).  You should handle it gracefully and re-open the stream.

Comment: Yeah why would you except the connection to remain open?

Comment: i want to continue the communication not by reopening the stream. how to handle it?